# ColorZone doesn't drop shadow in WPF MaterialDesign

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I try to make `ColorZone` in WPF using the [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) library. But when I set

```xml
materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth5"
```

it doesn't show any shadow. Below is a full code of the sample app where it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

1. I added `MaterialDesignThemes` to the project.
2. In `app.xaml` paste this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="TestShadow.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestShadow"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme
                    BaseTheme="Light"
                    PrimaryColor="DeepPurple"
                    SecondaryColor="Lime" />
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

3. And to `MainWindow.xaml` I added:

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestShadow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestShadow"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">

    <Grid>

        <materialDesign:ColorZone
            Mode="PrimaryDark"
            Padding="16"
            materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth5">

            <TextBlock
                Text="Material Design In XAML Toolkit"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        </materialDesign:ColorZone>

    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

Result, no shadow:

[image: result]

Comment: Which version of Material Design do you use?

Comment: MaterialDesignThemes - `3.2.0`. MaterialDesignColors - `1.2.7`

Comment: The Shadow is outside of the ColorZone so you may try to add a margin to the ColorZone to check if it isn't just hidden by the other contents. Margin="5" should be enough. If it work then try to put the color zone on the first plan to assure the shadow is over the other content

Comment: @XimazeC I added margin but I still don't see any shadow. The only way I have found to do it is to use Card and set Radius to `0`

Comment: Have you tried to put shadows on other element to try it out

Comment: As I mentioned I put shadows on `Card` and it is working. Also on any other Control like `Button`, `Toggles` I see shadows properly but not on this `ColorZone`

Comment: Am also having this problem,, its working in a previous project but now its not.

Comment: i think it has to do with the newer version,, ive just tested with a previous version and the drop shadow was there.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is some problem for the MaterialDesign current version. The only way I have found is to place the Card element under the ColorZone. In this case, the shadow becomes visible.